# CodeIgniter - ses_destroy() uses a LOT of CPU

Tags: mysql, session, codeigniter

I have a web-application written in CodeIgniter, and for the most part everything seems fairly reasonable. However, I've noticed extremely high CPU usage when a user logs out. My logout function in my auth controller is as follows:

```
function logout()
{
    $goto = $SERVER['HTTP-REFERER'];
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    if (!$goto)
        $goto = "/";
    header('location: '.$goto);
}
```

Normally, this is perfectly fine and fast. The strange thing is that when linked to **from a particular sub-page** this function takes about 5-6 seconds my of mysqld running at 100% cpu. How can I see what it's doing, and why?

Comment: Try commenting the `sess_detroy()` call, to be sure it is what makes this slow ; when you are sure it is, you'll need to tell us more about what this method does.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is going on when I call sess_destroy() -- it's just the CodeIgniter way of destroying your session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a shot in the dark (if you're sure this function is causing the slowness):

First, you could turn on MySQL's slow query log:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

Then, if `$sess_use_database` is `TRUE` you might try optimizing your session table. You could have some overhead causing issues.

Apart from that, the only other thing I can think of is that there is an issue with your DB server. You might try running the MySQL Tuner to see if you can improve things a bit:

https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl

Hope that helps!

**FYI**

Here is the code that is run when the OP runs `sess_destroy()` (from v2.0.2):

```
/**
 * Destroy the current session
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  void
 */
function sess_destroy()
{
    // Kill the session DB row
    if ($this->sess_use_database === TRUE AND isset($this->userdata['session_id']))
    {
        $this->CI->db->where('session_id', $this->userdata['session_id']);
        $this->CI->db->delete($this->sess_table_name);
    }

    // Kill the cookie
    setcookie(
                $this->sess_cookie_name,
                addslashes(serialize(array())),
                ($this->now - 31500000),
                $this->cookie_path,
                $this->cookie_domain,
                0
            );
}
```

Comment: I do indeed use `$sess_use_database` but why would my other database tables have any effect on clearing my entry in the sessions table? Thanks for the link on MySQL slow query log, i'll check it out

Comment: I'm not sure about the other tables, but if there is high fragmentation in your session table, that could cause slowness.

Comment: I'm marking this as accepted because "optimizing my tables" led me to not having the problem anymore... Thanks for your suggestions! I had a two-column primary-key index on a 2-col 0-row table... removing that *seems* to make the problem go away, although I have no idea why =\