# Innodb insert optimization

Tags: mysql, innodb

The following query takes 1-10 secs in inserting a single row

```
INSERT INTO site_stats (stats_id, page_id, stats_time) VALUES(N, N, NOW());
```

stats_id and page_id are INT

MySQL slow log

```
Count         : 80049 (26%)
Time          : 184467445311844 s total, 2304431602 s avg, 1 s to 18446744073709 s max
95% of Time   : 337702 s total, 4 s avg, 1 s to 78 s max
Lock Time     : 4145198 s total, 51 s avg, 0 s to 8377 s max
Rows sent     : 0 avg, 0 to 0 max
Rows examined : 0 avg, 0 to 0 max
```

Forgot to mention: I move records from this table to another every hour for providing stats to users. Usually more than 7000 rows are inserted in one hour

Comment: How many indexes on this table? Are there any other jobs running in the background that hit this table?

Comment: Are there any triggers that fire as a result of the insert?

Comment: @Jimmy: There is just one foreign key page_id and yes this table continuously hit in background during delete operation which occurs every hour. @Johan: No, there are no triggers.

Comment: How many rows are in this table? I've experience slow writes like this once the table hit 300 million rows and was 68G in size. I ended up having to archive a bunch of data to get my write speed back up.

Answer (score 0):

Try some of the methods I showed this guy here:

[CodeIgniter - ses_destroy() uses a LOT of CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688995/codeigniter-ses-destroy-uses-a-lot-of-cpu/5689050#5689050)

Also, remove some of your less important indexes. Having multiple indexes can slow down your write statements.

Comment: There is just one foreign key on page_id. Should I remove it?

Comment: How large is this table? Try optimizing and running MySQL tuner.

Comment: Its not much large. I have added extra information in the question. Thanks